# PhP массивы, выводит значение как ".."

Tags: php, массивы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Люди добрые! Почему первое значение массива PHP выводится как ".."? Нет никаких идей , всё перепробовала

Этот массив состоит из названий и ID3 тегов mp3 , загружаемых пользователем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите нам массив, и вообще код, мы же не телепаты.

Comment: вангую, что список файлов формируется через опрос директории, где присутствуют 2 виртуальных файла (каталога): "." и "..".

Comment: да , именно , через опрос директории!

Comment: но точек там нету и .htaccess тоже

Answer (score 1):

Точка это ссылка на текущую папку, две точки на родительную. Можно исключить их к примеру с помощь функции `array_diff`.

Comment: написала вот так " array_diff($files1['$num']); " не работает

Comment: Девушка хватит мотать нас за нос, покажите нам код. Покажите нам дамп массива.

Comment: array_diff не помогло

Comment: И не заработает так как выше, нужно `array_diff($files, ['.','..']);`

Comment: не помогло ((((

Comment: Значит что то не правильно делаете. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Всем спасибо!!! Вопрос решён! Алексей Щепкин , благодаря тебе!